# Setting multiple line values to a variable in GDB

Tags: c, debugging, testing, gdb

I have a char array `x` and I need to give it an input that spans multiple lines.

GDB takes input like `x:="value"` but how do I make it take values like

```
x := "this is a multiple lines
     input. We are now in second line"
```

Here the problem is not making GDB recognize  \n but to make my script readable when i give very long string inputs.

ex: instead of  x = "this is a very long text input. Very long input. very long input"
    i need to give x = "this is a very
                            long text input.
                            very long input.
                            very long input"

Answer (score 0):

I would expect embedded newline escapes to work:

```
gdb$ set var x = "this is a long\nstring with\nmultiple lines\in it!"
```

But I don't have access to gdb right now to try it.

Answer (score 0):

End the line with a backslash, and continue on the next line.

```
$ gdb s
(gdb) list
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   
3   char buf[512];
4   
5   main()
6   {
7       printf("%s\n", buf);
8   }
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483bd: file s.c, line 7.
(gdb) run
Starting program: s 

Breakpoint 1, main () at s.c:7
7       printf("%s\n", buf);
(gdb) set buf="I have always wished for my computer to be as easy to use \
as my telephone; my wish has come true because I can no longer figure out \
how to use my telephone. --Bjarne Stroustrup."
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
I have always wished for my computer to be as easy to use as my telephone; my wish has come true because I can no longer figure out how to use my telephone. --Bjarne Stroustrup.

Program exited with code 0262.
(gdb)
```